# Bernoulli's Equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, bernoulli-equation

[image]I have a doubt that why does bernoulli's equation doesn't work in some cases, even after considering streamline flow, for example consider the system in image, we can apply A1v=A2v' , where A1 and A2 are cross section area of A and B, and since the motion is streamline, and  both areas A1 and A2 are equal, so v=v'.

But now if we apply bernoulli's equation considering section AB to be of length L then due we find that v'>v as,

(1/2)(d)v² + (d)gh = (1/2)(d)(v')²

Where d is the density of liquid,

So both the relations contradict each other, what is the possible reason?

Comment: The bernoulli equation is a statement of conservation of energy and the continuity equation is a statement of conservation of mass.  Both have to apply at all times.

Comment: What does that mean, what is going to be the actual velocity then?

Comment: If the outlet pipe diameter is constant and the flow is incompressible, the velocity is constant throughout the outlet pipe.

Comment: Why is bernoulli's equation failing then, even though the motion is streamline

Comment: why is bernoulli's equation failing then, even though the motion is streamline

Comment: The bernoulli equation cannot fail because energy must be conserved.  Check for errors in your derivation.

Comment: @DavidWhite got it, thanks for the reply

Comment: What do you think the fluid streamlines look like approaching the exit hole of the tank at A?  Vertical?  Converging inward toward the exit pipe?